# Compactness nilpotent operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, spectral-theory

Let $A \in L(X) $, where $X$ is Banach space, and given $A^2 = 0$ then A is compact operator.

I found out spectrum of $A$ is zero, but I still can't understand, what should I do next.

Can someone help me with this task?

Comment: What is $X$? A Hilbert space?

Comment: $X$ is Banach space

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. As a counterexample, consider the following operators over $\ell^2(\Bbb C)$:
$$
P(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,\dots) = (0,x_2,0,x_4,0,\dots)\\
R(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots) = (0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)\\
A(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots) = (R \circ P)(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots) = (0,0,x_2,0,x_4,\dots).
$$
Verify that $A$ satisfies $A^2 = 0$. On the other hand, we can see that $A$ fails to be compact. One way to see that $A$ is not compact is to note that $A^* \circ A$ is a projection of infinite rank. Indeed, we have
$$
\begin{align}
A^* \circ A &= (R \circ P)^* \circ (R \circ P) = P^* \circ R^* \circ R \circ P 
\\ & = P^* \circ (R^* \circ R) \circ P = P \circ \operatorname{id}_X \circ P = P \circ P = P.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you explain, why infinite rank of $P$ implies compactness of $A$?

Comment: @Maxim If $A$ is compact, then $B\circ A$ would have to be compact for all $A$. So, if $A$ were compact, then $P= A^* \circ A$ would have to be compact.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It would be better if you posted your own question about this. That said, some authors require both the domain and codomain of $T$ to be Banach (i.e. complete) as a precondition for compactness. Where compactness is applied to more general operators, I'm pretty sure that your operator would fit the definition because it maps the unit ball to a relatively compact subset of $c_{00}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4759249/977780) is the precise question.